# Is there a program/application that will easily allow me to update my site frequently?

Tags: php, mysql, time, cron

EDIT: I have already set up my website, so using a cms isn't really an option.

Is there something that that is "rather" user friendly (as I do plan to use it quite often if there is such a thing) that will basically allow you to schedule a task of say, deleting the text "I am going camping tomorrow" and insert the text "I have gone camping" in between  and the  right after  at a specific time. Of course the program would need to be able upload the file at that specific time as well. This program should also be able to insert a record into phpmyadmin at a specific time as well.

I was going to look into Cron, but my host does not provide it. Should I switch host, or is there an alternative? Is Cron even capable of the thing I just described? If so would it be too complex (or not worth going thru the process everytime)? Is there another easier/better/alternative solution?

All inputs would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why is a CMS not an option just because you already set up your website?

Comment: If nothing else, yes, you should move if your host doesn't support cron.

Comment: Brad: I want to run my site completely free of CMS for various reasons, but setting up a cms now would be too much of a hassle, or at least so I think. Ceejaoz: So cron can do all that I described? If so, is it quick and/or easy?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a CMS, maybe like [wordpress](http://wordpress.org). You can schedule an item to publish in the future.

Comment: A CMS is the way to go. Everything you described is implemented, thousands of plugins exist, and you can write your own. Look at Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla to start :)

Comment: So turn it into a WordPress theme. Doesn't take long.

Comment: You will probably spend less time switching over to wordpress than you would setting up crons to change out content.

Comment: My site isn't blog themed... In fact, there's barely any words in the site. Mostly images.

Comment: wordpress is a general cms that does great even if you're not blogging. Also, you could still try joomla or drupal. You already have a fine approach if you don't want to use a cms that badly. Switch to a host that supports crons. Write a script for each individual change and schedule those scripts individually. In your question, you did leave the door open for better solution though, and a cms is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just point to a user's Twitter account and use that?  Or a GMail Calendar if you want to schedule it?  I'm assuming that you're using something like WordPress - which has plugins as I've described to do this task.

Comment: I have my own website, and it doesn't use a cms

Comment: WordPress isn't a CMS, but it can be used as such. Please consider using it as it will help you get up to speed quicker. There are many plugins that you can use and hack for your own usage.  There are "themes" which are for gallary type pages as you've suggested that your site is.